# Biologically, what are sirchos?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, science, parts-of-the-body

Biologically, what are [Sirchos](http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/dafyomi2/chulin/insites/ch-dt-049.htm)?

Are they a Tumor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Rabbi Yaacov Dovid Lach [explains](http://books.google.com/books?id=9Xz1v8ecNCUC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&source=bl&ots=6Yhee0QEzM&sig=mGXI6nToMQO96Lxk_MqLRM55lbA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VMhTVLXyN5HIsATJk4L4Dw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) in his book [Chullin Illuminated](http://books.google.com/books?id=9Xz1v8ecNCUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) they are a fibrous [adhesion](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=Adhesions) that connect parts of the lungs to each other or to the surrounding walls of the chest cavity. In healthy lungs they are not present and thus indicate a problem. The exact nature of this problem is a matter of dispute (it either is caused by a previously present wound healing but the wound can be expected to reopen, or the adhesion could cause a tear in the lung in the future as these parts of the lung are supposed to free standing to allow for the expansion and contraction of breathing).

Adhesions themselves can be caused by wounds or infection, so either side of the dispute is a plausible explanation of the adhesion. However, modern biology seems to attribute them in cattle [to infection](https://www.sdstate.edu/ars/species/beef/beef-reports/upload/2003-03-A-Preliminary-Assessment-of-Lung-Lesion-Distribution-in-fed-cattle.pdf), thus favoring the notion that the problem is a future tear in the lung, not a past one.

The general condition in cattle is described as lung leasions. Here is a link with pictures of several different ways that it presents. WARNING: Some may find such images disturbing. [Link](http://www.cvmbs.colostate.edu/ilm/proinfo/necropsy/notes/lungleasions.html).

I wasn't able to find a discussion of whether or not modern biology considers holes in lungs a possible outcome of lung leasions.

Comment: Is there a scientific name for them? You know like an egg has a chalaza.

Comment: @user6591 Adhesion is the scientific term. I guess a more colloquial term might be scar tissue. http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=Adhesions

Comment: Is your parenthetical statement true accd to modern biology?

Comment: @doubleaa, according to the link in my comment directly above, either opinion is consistent (IOW, it can be caused by wounds or infection). How it may impact a cow lung if left naturally, i don't know.

Answer (score -2):

It's a type of scab that forms over a hole in the lungs.

Comment: That is the the halachic description. Seems the OP wants to know the biological name for scabs that we call sirchos.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? Is there a scientific name for this phenomenon:?